# CoreLocation/Mapkit Altitude

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, core-location, altitude

Just a quick question, does CoreLocation/Mapkit measure altitude from sea level (elevation)?

I am using the following code

```
NSString *altitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f m", newLocation.altitude];
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check the altitude via the locationManager like this :

```
locationManager.location.altitude
```

you can also check the vertical accuracy with :

```
locationManager.location.verticalAccuracy
```

Comment: Do you know if this data comes from the device barometer or it's data from a flat map?